# Replace timeseries missing values with previous years value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

As the title suggests, I have an hourly df looks like this:

```
                        date_time               traffic_volume
date_time       
2012-10-02 09:00:00     2012-10-02 09:00:00     5545.0
2012-10-02 10:00:00     2012-10-02 10:00:00     4516.0
2012-10-02 11:00:00     2012-10-02 11:00:00     NaN
2012-10-02 12:00:00     2012-10-02 12:00:00     NaN
2012-10-02 13:00:00     2012-10-02 13:00:00     NaN
2012-10-02 14:00:00     2012-10-02 14:00:00     NaN
2012-10-02 15:00:00     2012-10-02 15:00:00     5584.0
2012-10-02 16:00:00     2012-10-02 16:00:00     6015.0
```

The majority of the NaNs I imputed using

```
df['traffic_volume'] = df['traffic_volume'].interpolate(method='time')
```

The problem now is that for a certain subset of time-series (the remaining NaN's), I want to impute by putting the same value  of that day but last year.
I used

```
df['traffic_volume'] =  df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[ x['date_time'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=-1)]['traffic_volume'] if x['traffic_volume']==np.NaN else x['traffic_volume'], axis=1)
```

The line of code ran but my NaN's weren't Imputed. My question is why? and if there is a better way what is it?

Thank you.

P.S The reason I don't want to use bfill, ffill or interpolate is because the sequence of NaN's are too much and the data loses granularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to use `pd.isna(x['traffic'])` instead of `x['traffic_volume']==np.NaN` for the `if` condition in the `lambda`. I still don't understand why the initial line ran but didn't impute.